# Get network time in flutter - Offline mode?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

Do we have any flutter/native iOS plugins to get the network time during offline mode? Or Is there any option to track the date time automatically settings in iOS device?

Comment: How can you possibly get the time from the network while not connected to a network?

Comment: yes, that's it! I am checking the possibility to get time from the network provider without internet connection or to notify the app once the user changed "Set Automatically" settings inside the Date & Time. Any option?

Answer (score 0):

1. 

If you want to get datetime from device , U can use :

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

main() {
static final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
static final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
final String formatted = formatter.format(now);
print(formatted); // something like 2013-04-20
}
```

2. If you want to fetch date time from internet you must enable internet in your  device and Use this package to get date time from internet.
   https://pub.dev/packages/ntp